# Changing the statement delimiter to something other than ; with #define

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I am using #define to define the chinese period 。as the delimiter:

```
#define 。 ;
```

That gives an error when executing the following code:

```
main() {
int i = 0 。
return i 。
}
```

Error:

```
<stdin>: In function ‘main’:
<stdin>:11:22: error: universal character \U00003002 is not valid in an identifier
<stdin>:11:22: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘。’
<stdin>:12:21: error: universal character \U00003002 is not valid in an identifier
<stdin>:14:1: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input
```

However when I define 'yes' as ;, it works.

Comment: Well, `universal character \U00003002 is not valid in an identifier`.  CPP uses UTF-8 not UTF-16. Change your file encoding to utf-8

Comment: experimenting with c preprocesor...

Comment: An interesting experiment, but it will never work. The preprocessor is designed for replacing things that look like identifiers, not arbitrary punctuation.

Comment: what do you mean by 'look like identifiers'?

Comment: Maybe skip the `#define` and use `tr 。 ';' <source.chinese >source.c` as a pre-pre-processor step in your shell: **not tested**.

Comment: That wouldn't work in something like printf("。")。

Answer (score 1):

From the C11 standard section 6.10.3 on macro replacements:

> A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> define identifier replacement-list new-line
>
> defines an object-like macro that causes each subsequent instance of the macro name 171) to be replaced by the replacement list of preprocessing tokens that constitute the
>   remainder of the directive. The replacement list is then rescanned for more macro names
>   as specified below.

And here on section 6.4.2.1:

> Syntax
>
> identifier:
>
> identifier-nondigit
>
> identifier identifier-nondigit
>
> identifier digit
>
> identifier-nondigit:
>
> nondigit
>
> universal-character-name
>
> other implementation-defined characters
>
> nondigit: one of
>   _ a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
>
> digit: one of
>   0 1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Note that universal character names mentioned above are escape sequences, not the actual character as a UTF-8 or UTF-16 sequence.

It's not possible to do what you're trying to do according to the standard, because an identifier cannot contain the Chinese period character (regardless of what encoding it's in.)

You can try using a different preprocessor than cpp. You'll have to find one that allows that character as a textual substitution key (the downside being that you lose all other cpp directives.) I don't know of any that allow that. M4, for example, has the same restriction on character sets in identifiers.

Comment: Will it work if I edit the GCC source? if so what file?

Comment: You can check out https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/33bb12b1ed4b88023f8076822807d648cab9c899/libcpp/lex.c#L1319.

Comment: Hacking the compiler to do what you want is a waste of time. Your code won't be portable to any other compiler, plus you'll forever have to merge upstream changes to gcc to keep your fork current. Best to learn to program in the language as it's defined.

Comment: @paulJ.Lucas it's not a waste of time if you learn something in the process.